# How to input array of objects in input value field from Vue.js?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have this array:

```
[{"ID":"1","Shasi":"VF157469762","Brand":"82","Model":"CLIO IV Societe Life","Nomer":"C3KK","Insurence":"\u0417\u0410\u0414 \u0410410 \u0418\u041d\u0428\u0423\u0420\u042a\u041d\u0421 \u0413\u0420\u0423\u041f \u0410\u0414","Grajdanska":"\u0417\u0410\u0414 \u0411\u0423\u041b\u0421\u0422\u0420\u0410\u0414 \u0412\u0418\u0415\u041d\u0410 \u0418\u041d\u0428\u0423\u0420\u042a\u041d\u0421 \u0413\u0420\u0423\u041f \u0410\u0414","Given":"0000-00-00","ContractN":"0040000434","ContractType":"ZMV","CustomerN":"1100024801","CustomerName":"\u041d\u0415\u0421\u0422\0413\u0410\u0420\u0418\u042f \u0410\u0414","Vat":"8349","OwnerN":"","OwnerName":"","OwnerVAT":"","ContractDate":"2021-02-28","GTP":"2019-04-30","NextTO":"2020-04-19","TON":"98015","GO":"2019-04-27","Kasko":"2021-04-28","Vinetka":"2019-01-31","Total":"2490"},{"ID":"2","Shasi":"VF16RB9763","Brand":"82","Model":"CLIO IV Societe Life","Nomer":"C16KM","Insurence":"\u0417\u0410\u0414 \u0411\u0423\u041b\u0421\u0422\u0420\u0410\u0414 \u0412\u0418\u0415\u041d\u0410 \u0418\u041d\u0428\u0423\u0420\u042a\u041d\u0421 \u0413\u0420\u0423\u041f \u0410\u0414","Grajdanska":"\u0417\u0410\u0414 \u0411\u0423\u041b\u0421\u0422\u0420\u0410\u0414 \u0412\u0418\u0415\u041d\u0410 \u0418\u041d\u0428\u0423\u0420\u042a\u041d\u0421 \u0413\u0420\u0423\u041f \u0410\u0414","Given":"0000-00-00","ContractN":"00434","ContractType":"ZMV","CustomerN":"1101","CustomerName":"\u041d\u04041b\u0415 \u0411\u042a\u041b\u0042f \u0410\u0414","Vat":"8349","OwnerN":"","OwnerName":"","OwnerVAT":"","ContractDate":"2021-02-28","GTP":"2019-05-03","NextTO":"2019-02-02","TON":"5969","GO":"2020-05-11","Kasko":"2021-05-12","Vinetka":"2019-01-31"}]
```

I want to be able to put it inside input value like this:

```
<form action="exportToExcel.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" v-model="cars">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Експортирай към Excel">
</form>
```

But what I end-up getting is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]">
```

What I am doing wrong? I tried with `:value`, but I am getting the same result. Thanks!

Comment: @mathk answer is correct. A little bit addition is if backend is PHP you can get your array as `$data = json_decode(json_encode($_POST), true);` . And there will be your array of data to create file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `:value=JSON.stringify(cars)`.

Though it looks very old school to rely on form this days. I advise to use lib like axios for submitting form data and remove the need of an hidden input

Comment: thanks for your answer. the thing is that i need to send the data to other php page where i want to transform the data and create an xml file, im not use if i can do this only using axios...